# ArrayBuffer not working with Float64Array Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to get a Float64Array to work with an array buffer but node will just not have it. When I do this....

```
   var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);

   var view = new Uint8Array(ab);

   console.log(view.length);//prints 3204
```

But when I do this...

```
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);

var view = new Float64Array(ab);

console.log(view.length);//prints nothing
```

I have also tried...

```
var view = new Float64Array(ab,0,buffer.length);
```

And still doesn't work.

Can anybody shed a light on why I cant access this 64 bit array? The buffer was just read from a file which is meant to be 64 bit array of floating point numbers. I just need to get access to it.

Comment: I just tried something like that in Node 0.10.25 and it worked fine. What's the value of `buffer.length`? (oh; 3200 duhh)

Comment: actually the size was 3204 which is what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just realised my unit testing framework was swallowing an exception which told me that the length of the buffer that goes into Float64Array must be a multiple of 8. But the file I am reading obviously has a header or something!

So I adjusted the size and it works.